# Gradle: How to set signingConfig in buildTypes for multi-dimension flavors

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors, android-flavordimension

I have got the following error log when I synchronise my grade file in Android Studio (v2.2):

```
Error:(184, 0) Could not get unknown property 'freeAppDev' for ProductFlavor container.
```

Background:

I have an app of 2 versions (e.g. freeApp & paidApp) for 3 development environments (e.g. dev, uat & production). I set my app.gradle file like this:

```
flavorDimensions "ver", "env"

productFlavors {
    freeApp {
        dimension "ver"
        ...
    }
    paidApp {
        dimension "ver"
        ...
    }

    dev {
        dimension "env"
        ...
    }
    uat {
        dimension "env"
        ...
    }
    production {
        dimension "env"
        ...
    }
}
```

For the buildTypes, I created a customised debug type "alpha" such that I can set signingConfig for my own purpose:

```
buildTypes {
    alpha {
        productFlavors.freeAppDev.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom1DebugKey
        productFlavors.freeAppUat.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom2DebugKey
        productFlavors.freeAppProduction.signingConfig signingConfigs.customReleaseKey

        productFlavors.paidAppDev.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom1DebugKey
        productFlavors.paidAppUat.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom2DebugKey
        productFlavors.paidAppProduction.signingConfig signingConfigs.customReleaseKey
    }
    ...
}
```

custom1DebugKey, custom2DebugKey, customReleaseKey are signingConfigs which is not the point so I just skip pasting the code.

I would like to ask how I could get the correct name for XXX in "productFlavors.XXX.signingConfig" when there are more than one dimensions in productFlavors. Thanks.

P.S. For more information, it works perfectly for me by modifying the gradle file like this:

```
productFlavors {
    freeAppDev {
        ...
    }
    freeAppUat {
        ...
    }
    freeAppProduction {
        ...
    }

    paidAppDev {
        ...
    }
    paidAppUat {
        ...
    }
    paidAppProduction {
        ...
    }
}


buildTypes {
    alpha {
        productFlavors.freeAppDev.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom1DebugKey
        productFlavors.freeAppUat.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom2DebugKey
        productFlavors.freeAppProduction.signingConfig signingConfigs.customReleaseKey

        productFlavors.paidAppDev.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom1DebugKey
        productFlavors.paidAppUat.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom2DebugKey
        productFlavors.paidAppProduction.signingConfig signingConfigs.customReleaseKey
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Did you get any success? If yes, could you please port your solution.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're assigning the signing key based only on environment:

```
productFlavors.freeAppDev.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom1DebugKey
productFlavors.freeAppUat.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom2DebugKey
productFlavors.freeAppProduction.signingConfig signingConfigs.customReleaseKey

productFlavors.paidAppDev.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom1DebugKey
productFlavors.paidAppUat.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom2DebugKey
productFlavors.paidAppProduction.signingConfig signingConfigs.customReleaseKey
```

If that's the case, you could just use that:

```
productFlavors.dev.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom1DebugKey
productFlavors.uat.signingConfig signingConfigs.custom2DebugKey
productFlavors.production.signingConfig signingConfigs.customReleaseKey
```

Note that the `productFlavors` will contain every product flavor (In your case: freeApp, paidApp, dev, uat, production), but won't combine them based on dimension like you're trying to use them.